# googletrans source language issue (pandas dataframe operation)

Tags: python, pandas, google-translate

I used this script to change the language of the columns:

```
translations = {}
for column in df_en.columns:
    # unique elements of the column
    unique_elements = df_en[column].unique()
    for element in unique_elements:
        # add translation to the dictionary
        translations[element] = translator.translate(element).text
df_en.replace(translations, inplace = True)
```

The database is pretty big and it would be time consuming so I decided to check one of the columns on this way:

```
translations = {}
# unique elements of the column
unique_elements = df["Operation Description"].unique()

for element in unique_elements:
    # add translation to the dictionary
    translations[element] = translator.translate(element).text
```

**EDIT**
The script is working. I don't know why, but sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't.